I found a problem while exchainging the tensorflow backend of keras3 to the jax backend
I have a NN model based on a keras.model. It works when I use TensorFlow, but I was trying to use it for jax. So, I changed the back-end to jax and suddenly I have to create an aux variable in the training step, because now I have more inputs to the custom class and for some reason calling self for getting the prediction of the network returns an error.
I tried defining different types of jax arrays for trying to make self() work, but it may be failing because I am not using the extra input I now receive. This is the important part of the code:
class ODE_2nd(keras.Model):


    def set_ODE_param(self,z0,r0,r0_grad,n, epsilon):
        '''
        Set parameters and initial conditions for the ODE
        '''
        #self.z0=z0
        #self.z0=jnp.array(z0)
        self.z0 = jnp.full((1, 1), float(z0[0]), dtype=jnp.float32)
        self.r0_true=r0
        self.r0_true_grad=r0_grad
        self.n=n
        self.epsilon=epsilon

    #@jax.jit
    def train_step(self, aux, data):
        '''
        Training ocurrs here
        '''
        print(f"data={data}")
        print(f"aux={aux}")
        z, r_true= data

        #* initial conditions
        print(f"z0={self.z0}")
        print(help(self))
        r0_pred=self(self.z0, training=False)
        dr_dzpred0=jax.grad(r0_pred, self.z0)


initializer = keras.initializers.GlorotUniform(seed=5)
activation='tanh'
input=Input(shape=(input_neurons,))
x=Dense(100, activation=activation,kernel_initializer=initializer)(input)
#x=Dense(100, activation=activation,kernel_initializer=initializer)(x)
#x=Dense(100, activation=activation,kernel_initializer=initializer)(x)
output = Dense(output_neurons,kernel_initializer=initializer,activation=None)(x)

# Build the model
model=ODE_2nd(input,output)

# Set ODE parameters and initial conditions
model.set_ODE_param(z0=[z0],r0=r0,r0_grad=r0_grad, n=n, epsilon=epsilon) #(dx_dz0=dx_dz0,A=A)

print(model.fit)
history=model.fit(z_train, y_train, batch_size=1, epochs=epochs,verbose=1) #,shuffle=False)

And this is the output:
aux=([Traced<ShapedArray(float32[1,100])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>, Traced<ShapedArray(float32[100])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>, Traced<ShapedArray(float32[100,1])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>, Traced<ShapedArray(float32[1])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>], [], [Traced<ShapedArray(int32[])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>, Traced<ShapedArray(float32[])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>, Traced<ShapedArray(float32[1,100])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>, Traced<ShapedArray(float32[1,100])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>, Traced<ShapedArray(float32[100])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>, Traced<ShapedArray(float32[100])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>, Traced<ShapedArray(float32[100,1])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>, Traced<ShapedArray(float32[100,1])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>, Traced<ShapedArray(float32[1])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>, Traced<ShapedArray(float32[1])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>], [Traced<ShapedArray(float32[])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>, Traced<ShapedArray(float32[])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>, Traced<ShapedArray(float32[])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>, Traced<ShapedArray(float32[])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>])
data=(Traced<ShapedArray(float32[1,1])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>, Traced<ShapedArray(float32[1,1])>with<DynamicJaxprTrace(level=1/0)>)
z0=[[0.05]]

TypeError: Exception encountered when calling Dense.call().

'NoneType' object is not callable

Arguments received by Dense.call():
  • inputs=jnp.ndarray(shape=(1, 1), dtype=float32)


Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.
